# Movement of Azure SQL databases from Azure standard subscription to dev/test subscription

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-devtest-labs

I have Azure Standard subscription, few azure SQL databases which are related to non-prod running on this subscription. Now I have purchased dev/test subscription . I am planning to move those databases/server from Standard subscription to dev/test subscription. I want to know whether it's possible to move to dev/test subscription. Do we have any limitation to move dev/test sub.

Also, will there be any impact to the AAD users(exist on the databases/subscription level) during the movement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is absolutely possible, just to make sure:

There wont be any impact on the Azure Active Directory if the lies in same tenant.

> Both the source and destination Azure Active Directory subscriptions must be in the same Azure Active Directory tenancy.

> The resources you wish to relocate must be compatible with the relocation operation. See Move operation support for resources for a list of resources that assist moving.

> The subscriptions to the source and destination must both be active.

During the move procedure, the source and target groups are locked. Until the transfer is finished, write and delete actions on resource groups are restricted. You can't make changes to resources in resource groups if they're locked.

This does not imply that the resources have been frozen. Applications that use the databases will not experience any downtime if you migrate an Azure SQL logical server and its databases to a different resource group or subscription. They still have access to the databases and can read and write to them. Although the lock can last up to four hours, most movements are completed in considerably less time.

**Note:** A child resource cannot be transferred separately from its parent resource in most situations.

**Please check this Microsoft Document to see which SQL** : Move operation support for resources |  [Microsoft.Sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftsql)